# in-app purchase is not working android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

in my project in-app purchase is implemented and in testing every thing was proper but after publishing it in market customers are reporting that their money got deducted but they have not got content.

I have received money in my google merchant account. I am not getting what is the issue. can any one help me out?

Comment: is that possible to put the detail where you chucking item purchased or not and to deliver/ display the content??

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue I am using shared preference to store state of transaction but in my final build i was not calling commit on shared preference editor.